# Filtering files returned by search box QT

Tags: c++, qt

```
QString search = ui->searchComboBox->currentText();
if(search.isEmpty()){
    search = "*";
}

files = currentDirectory.entryList(QStringList(search),
    QDir::Files | QDir::NoSymLinks);
```

This code returns files when the `QString` search is empty.
However, when I enter any text into the `searchComboBox`, there are no results.

For example, if there is a file in the directory I search called 'don300.png' and I search for 'don', I'm getting no results.

No sure how it works when trying to search for a string anywhere within the filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search pattern without wildcards will perform an exact match. In your case if text box is not empty then it'll match only with **exactly that name**. Just change your code to:

```
QString search = ui->searchComboBox->currentText() + "*";
files = currentDirectory.entryList(QStringList(search),
    QDir::Files | QDir::NoSymLinks);
```

If `searchComboBox` is empty then search will be `*` and if you'll provide a filter then search pattern will be (for example) `don*` (matching all files that *begins* with `don`).

In general you may want to match text more freely so you may use this:

```
QString search = ui->searchComboBox->currentText();
if(search.isEmpty()) {
    search = "*";
} else {
    search = "*" + search + "*";
}

files = currentDirectory.entryList(QStringList(search),
    QDir::Files | QDir::NoSymLinks);
```

Just for reference:

```
    Search pattern    Results
    *                 Any file.
    don*              Files that begin with "don".
    *don*             Files that contain "don".
```

Comment: That's a great answer and explanation bud. I tried to use % for the wildcards, as that's what I've used in other languages but it didn't work. I needed to know that * is used for this! Works great, thanks :)